Select a default value for the pivot table filter using ep plus
I was working on generating an Excel file in a .NET project using the EPPlus library. The Excel file contains a pivot table, and I need to set a default value for one of the page (filter) fields so that when the file is opened, the pivot table is filtered by that default value.
Here’s what I have done to achieve this:
I have used the SelectSingleItem method from the library to select the default value. In this method, you need to pass the index of the default filter value, ensuring that the value is present in your filter.
/// Your code
   pageField.Items.Refresh();
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in pageField.Items)
    {
        if (defaultFilterValue.Equals(item.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            break;
        index++;
    }
    pageField.Items.SelectSingleItem(index);

/// Your code
Demo code:-https://github.com/mayank748/PivotTableDefaultSelection
https://medium.com/@smayank748/setting-a-default-value-in-a-pivot-table-filter-using-epplus-a-step-by-step-guide-cbb7bce73fe1
Looked into the documentation of ep plus and this method helped me.
